# How do i host my website from my ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, server, hosting, web-hosting, ubuntu-server

I have taken a domain name, like `example.tk`, from `www.freenom.com`, hosting storage from `www.infinityfree.com`. My website is running successfully.

Now I want to host my website from my Ubuntu 18.04. I have already installed Apache, PHP and created a website which is running locally on localhost.

How can I set that `example.tk` to point to my locally running website and be accessible from anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache Config you should set

```
ServerName example.tk
```

than your server need to react to this IP. Edit `/etc/hosts` and add

```
YOUR.EXTERNAL.IP    example.tk
```

And of course your firewall at your provider need to accept the website ports `80` and if ussing https `443` too.

Comment: Yes i have done all those things, I followed this steps https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Did you set at freenom.com that example.tk links to your IP at infinityfree.com ?

Comment: I want example.tk, which is my domain to point my IP instead of infinityfree.com provides hosting space.

Comment: Your IP at home ? Do you have a static IP ? In general external IPs at home are changing every 24h.

Comment: Yes IP at home. No dynamic IP.

Comment: Same way! Configure your domain at freenom.com to point to your home IP. Set your server to identify itself with it in ````/etc/hosts````. And if you are using a NAT Router activate a forwarding for Port 80 and 443 (if https) to your home server.

Comment: Changing the IP at freenom.com may take some time (up to 24h I guess)!

Comment: Si it asking for name server also. Not only the ip

Comment: Do it like described in the knowledgebase and set an A record for your IP. https://my.freenom.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=4